# How can I use threadlocal variable with ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I want to threads has some local variable, with `thread.Thread` it can be done like this elegantly:

```
class TTT(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, lines, ip, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._lines = lines;
        self._sock = initsock(ip, port)
        self._sts = 0
        self._cts = 0

    def run(self):
        for line in self._lines:
            query = genquery(line)
            length = len(query)
            head = "0xFFFFFFFE"
            q = struct.pack('II%ds'%len(query),  head,  length, query)
            sock.send(q)
            sock.recv(4)
            length,  = struct.unpack('I',  sock.recv(4))
            result = ''
            remain = length
            while remain:
                t = sock.recv(remain)
                result+=t
                remain-=len(t)
            print(result)
```

As you can see that `_lines` `_sock` `_sts` `_cts` these variable will be independent in every thread.

But with `concurrent.future.ThreadPoolExecutor`, it seems that it's not that easy. With `ThreadPoolExecutor`, how can I make things elegantly?(no more global variables)

---

New Edited

```
class Processor(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self._sock = self._init_sock(host, port)

    def __call__(self, address, adcode):
        self._send_data(address, adcode)
        result = self._recv_data()
        return json.loads(result)

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    adcode = {"shenzhen": 440300}[args.city]

    if args.output:
        fo = open(args.output, "w", encoding="utf-8")
    else:
        fo = sys.stdout
    with open(args.file, encoding=args.encoding) as fi, fo,\
        ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=args.processes) as executor:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fi)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fo, reader.fieldnames + ["crfterm"])
        test_set = AddressIter(args.file, args.field, args.encoding)
        func = Processor(args.host, args.port)
        futures = map(lambda x: executor.submit(func, x, adcode), test_set)
        for row, future in zip(reader, as_completed(futures)):
            result = future.result()
            row["crfterm"] = join_segs_tags(result["segs"], result["tags"])
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Your functions can actually be callable objects.

Comment: Show what you are doing now with the thread pool and I'll tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist wait a minute

Comment: @MadPhysicist is these detail enough?

Comment: Sure, I was looking more for your attempt at using the thread pool, but my answer remains basically accurate.

Comment: Sorry , on mobile

Comment: specifically, are you planning on using map or submit in a loop ?

Comment: @MadPhysicist are they different? I am more familiar with `map`

Comment: map basically loops over multiple submits for you.

Answer (score 2):

Using a layout very similar to what you have now would be the easiest thing. Instead of a `Thread`, have a normal object, and instead of `run`, implement your logic in `__call__`:

```
class TTT:
    def __init__(self, lines, ip, port):
        self._lines = lines;
        self._sock = initsock(ip, port)
        self._sts = 0
        self._cts = 0

    def __call__(self):
        ...
        # do stuff to self
```

Adding a [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-callable-objects) method to a class makes it possible to invoke instances as if they were regular functions. In fact, normal functions are objects with such a method. You can now pass a bunch of `TTT` instances to either [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) or [`submit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit).

Alternatively, you could absorb the initialization into your task function:

```
def ttt(lines, ip, port):
    sock = initsock(ip, port)
    sts = cts = 0
    ...
```

Now you can call `submit` with the correct parameter list or `map` with an iterable of values for each parameter.

I would prefer the former approach for this example because it opens the port outside the executor. Error reporting in executor tasks can be tricky sometimes, and I would prefer to make the error prone operation of opening a port as transparent as possible.

**EDIT**

Based on your related question, I believe that the real question you are asking is about function-local variables (which are automatically thread-local as well), not being shared between function calls on the same thread. However, you can always pass references between function calls.

Comment: I add my new code, with `__call__` and `submit` but how to use the class?

Comment: In my code, `Processor` is just init one time, if I do `executor.submit(Processor(args.host, args.port), x, adcode)`, it will init every time.

Comment: @roger #1 that actually means that all your threads share the state and you aren't asking what you think you are. #2, you can always do `proc = Processor(...); executor.submit(proc, ...)`

Comment: yes, my code is all thread share the same state, and `proc = Processor(...); executor.submit(proc, ...)`, this also means that the `proc` is not thread bind,   what I want is still I want to `_sock ` variable is thread bind variable

Comment: I combing my question, I ask a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901594/how-to-bind-some-variable-to-thread-with-concurrent-futures-threadpoolexecutor-o